# how to dynamically add images in a nested loop (in template.docx) with xdocreport and velocity

Tags: java, velocity, docx, aspose, xdocreport

please i want to dynamically add images in a nested loop, i use docx as template.
i use xdocreport 1.0.2 and velocity.

here is my code:

```
List<Obect> structureList=new arrayList<Object>();



HashMap<String, Object> structureMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for(Structure sutructure:structureList){

      List<Obect> orientationList=new arrayList<Object>();

      //orientation can be vertical or horizontal;

        for(Orientation orientation: OrientationList){

         HashMap<String, Object> orientationMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

         List<Obect> projectionList=new arrayList<Object>();

               for(integer projection: projectionList){

             HashMap<String, Object> projectionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                     projectionMap.put("projectionImage",  getImageproviderByOrientationAndProjection(orientation, projection);

                       projectionList.add(projectionMap);

              }

     orientationMap.put("projections", projectionList); 

     orientationList.add(orientationMap);

      }
    structureMap.put("orientation", orientationList);

     structureList.add(structureMap);

   }
```

context("structures", structureList)

---

//my metadata are setting like this:

metadata.addFieldAsImage("projectionImage", "projection.projectionImage");

---

in my template(.docx) i do this:

```
 "#"foreach($structure in $structures){

      "#"foreach($orientation in $structure.orientations){

           "#"for($projection in $orientation.projections){

         //print image by projection

           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I suggest you to create an issue at https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/list with your docx+images+simple main which works.

Comment: thank a lot for your suggestion, i will do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use POJO as described in the samples (DeveloperWithImage.java)

```
/* Load the photos as list in the metadata */
FieldsMetadata metadata = report.createFieldsMetadata();
metadata.load( "photos", Photo.class, true );
report.setFieldsMetadata(metadata);

List<Photo> photos = ...
context.put( "photos", photos );
```

The Photo.java:

```
public class Photo {
private IImageProvider photo;

@FieldMetadata( images = { @ImageMetadata( name = "photo" ) }, description="Photo"  )
public IImageProvider getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(IImageProvider photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}}
```